# how to handle jQuery ajax URL changes?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a web service at:

> **/localhost/portal/** *WebServices/InformationNoticeUtility.asmx/InformationNoticesGet*

when user goes to another page for example:

> **/localhost/portal/Reporting/**

and tries to call this web service using jquery Ajax, it will fail because jquery replaces the url of the web service to the following url:

> **/localhost/portal/Reporting/** *WebServices/InformationNoticeUtility.asmx/InformationNoticesGet*

Is there any way I could pass in an object to overcome this error?

Comment: How are you setting jQuery.ajaxSettings?

Comment: Can't you just do `../WebServices/InformationNoticeUtility.asmx/InformationNoticesGet` on the `Reporting` page? Or use absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code would help, but do you have a `<base>` tag on your page? If so, that may be causing your unexpected results. If not, you may actually desire that behavior and might want to try it.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) for a good discussion of caveats.